# How to translate Text string inside title include using trans

Tags: twig

I need to translate the 'Welcome' title , example:

```
{% include 'index.html.twig' with {'title': 'Welcome' } %}
```

But symphony does not let me to translate it using trans, I tried :

```
{% include 'index.html.twig' with {'title': '{% trans%}Welcome{% endtrans %}' } %}  
{% include 'index.html.twig' with {'title': {% trans%}'Welcome'{% endtrans %} } %}
```

But I did not worked out.

Please, if you know how, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it doing :

```
{% include 'index_toolbar.html.twig' with {'title':'Usuaris'|trans} %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress it's as easy as this - however I am assuming that you aren't using Wordpress?
https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/internationalization/

```
{{ __('Welcome', 'my-text-domain') }}
```

Comment: Hi, no, just symphony.

Comment: sorry about that then :(